# Gunicorn not installing correctly in virtualenv or otherwise

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I am currently trying to deploy my app using Amazon EC2. I am using `gunicorn` and Nginx. When I install `gunicorn` within my `virtualenv` I am getting the following error...

```
Downloading/unpacking gunicorn
  Downloading gunicorn-19.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112kB): 112kB downloaded
Installing collected packages: gunicorn
Compiling /home/ubuntu/env/build/gunicorn/gunicorn/workers/_gaiohttp.py ...
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/build/gunicorn/gunicorn/workers/_gaiohttp.py", line 78
    yield from self.wsgi.close()
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Successfully installed gunicorn
Cleaning up...
```

I suspect this is the reason I am unable to get `gunicorn` to work correctly with my app. How can I get gunicorn installed correctly?

Comment: SyntaxError you are getting is just a warning: https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/788